# How to create database INDEX for SQL expression?

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, database-indexes

I am beginner with indexes. I want to create index for this SQL expression which takes too much time to execute so I would like on what exact columns should I create index?
 I am using DB2 db but never mind I think that question is very general.

My SQL expression is:

```
select * from incident  where (relatedtoglobal=1) 
and globalticketid in (select ticketid from INCIDENT where status='RESOLVED')
     and statusdate <='2012-10-09 12:12:12'
```

Should I create index with this 5 columns or how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your query:

```
select * 
from incident  
where relatedtoglobal = 1 
  and globalticketid in ( select ticketid 
                          from INCIDENT 
                          where status='RESOLVED'
                        )
  and statusdate <='2012-10-09 12:12:12' ;
```

And the subquery inside:

```
select ticketid 
from INCIDENT 
where status='RESOLVED'
```

- An index on `(status, ticketid)` will certainly help efficiency of the subquery evaluation and thus of the query.
- For the query, besides the previous index, you'll need one more index. The `(relatedtoglobal, globalticketid)` may be sufficient.

I'm not sure if a more complex indexing would/could be used by the DB2 engine.

- Like one on `(relatedtoglobal, globalticketid) INCLUDE (statusdate)` or
- Two indices, one  on `(relatedtoglobal, globalticketid)` and one on `(relatedtoglobal, statusdate)`

---

The DB2 documentation is not an easy read but has many details. Start with **[CREATE INDEX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000919.htm)** statement and **[Implementing Indexes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.admin%2Fbjnddimp1046555.htm)**.

Comment: THANKS for helpful answer..but sorry what are the indices?

Comment: Ok thank you.. how to know maximum of indexes that I can create? Because  I know they will slow down insert update delete..so how not to break some maximum value for the system that will slow down my applications

Comment: and one mor equestion what is INCLUDE (statusdate)? should I add  this statement  when creating index?

Comment: Don't worry about performance problems, especially those you suspect upon INSERT and UPDATE if you don't have them. That's premature optimization.

Comment: Hi thanks for help I have some progresses thanks to you two. But I still have one dilemma. For this query which takes me too much time select * from TABLE  where (upper(COLUMN1) like '%HGW%'))  should I create index or not? Because of LIKE and UPPER statements. What is your proposal? Will index have affect in this case or not? THANKS

Comment: Indexing will (usually) not help `LIKE '%text%'` conditions.